# How to link a library package of C# in Visual Studio 2022 so that I can use it every time in any solution or project?

Tags: c#, package, visual-studio-2022

I have some libraries like `Colorful.Console` from GitHub, I used to use it frequently. Every time I started a new project, I have to install this library *de novo*. How can I install it so that it became available every time?

Answer (score 0):

Use the NuGet package for it

1. Go to Tools >> NuGet Package Manager >> Manage Packages for Solution
2. Click on the "Browse Tab"
3. Type in "Colorful" and the package will appear
4. Add it to the projects you need.

You'll find NuGet packages for many of the things on GitHub.  That's the best way to re-use them.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**
Create a new console project, add the desired NuGet package(s). Next export the project as a [project template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2022). Make sure to provide a meaningful name for each template. Here are [some example templates](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/vs2019-custom-project-templates).

**Option 2**
Open a project up with the desired NuGet package(s) installed, in solution explorer double click the project node, select the `ItemGroup` with the package. Drag it to the IDE toolbox then optionally right click on the new item and give it a meaningful name.

To use it in a new project, open the project file as done above and drag the code from the toolbox into the project file, save it then Visual Studio will download the package.

[image]

Which is better? it dependents on what suits you, I always use exported project templates and sometimes use the toolbox method along with Resharper which allows creating of snippets that can be used in project files similar to option 2 but not stored in the toolbox.